ActionFilter to limit api exection time for configure time only. What is wrong with this implementation
public class TimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly int _timeoutInMilliseconds;
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
    public TimeoutAttribute(int timeoutInMilliseconds)
    {
        _timeoutInMilliseconds = timeoutInMilliseconds;
        _timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInMilliseconds);
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(_timeout);
            try
            {
                await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cts.Token);                    
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, ApiErrorMessages.RequestTimeout);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}

I have written this TimeoutAttribute to limit execution time and set upper cap time limit to Api action. However it is not working as expected , can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Did you register your implementation with the DI container?  What's wrong with the built in timeout mechanism?

No need to register as no such dependencies I need to resolve, I have register this as global filter
